# Audio recording with Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to find my way setting audio recording in a little Next JS app of mine.
For that I got started using this document: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-video-audio-recorder-react/

I am at the point where I have the following code:

```
...
const mrRef = useRef(null);
...
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream!, { mimeType: mimeType });
mrRef.current = mediaRecorder;
```

For the last line above, in Visual Studio Code I see the warning below:

```
Type 'MediaRecorder' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
(property) MutableRefObject<null>.current: null
```

I do not quite understand what is wrong. What am I suppose to do here?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't type your ref value.

Here's a naive solution:

```js
const mrRef = useRef<any>(null);

mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream!, { mimeType: mimeType });
mrRef.current = mediaRecorder;
```

this is not good practice, you should find a type declaration for what MediaRecorder returns and type your ref as

```js
const mrRef = useRef<MediaRecorderType || null>(null);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).